# Output with single quote inside

Tags: php, symfony1

I am using Symfony, but I think this is a general PHP problem to solve.

```
$yaml[UtilInc::getSfEnvironment()]['a']['b'] = "'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '15', '16'";
```

to make my yml file store:

```
a: { b: '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '15', '16'}
```

but it just kept storing it as:

```
a: { b: '''1'', ''2'', ''3'', ''4'', ''5'', ''6'', ''7'', ''8'', ''9'', ''10'', ''11'', ''12'', ''13'', ''15'', ''16'''}
```

I have tried various pattern such as escaping, used double quotes with combination of single quotes, etc., but I still couldn't get the result I want.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are talking about PHP without framework or whatever you are using, including `'` in a string is as simple as this:

```
<?php
$v = "'a'";
echo $v;
?>
```

will output:

```
'a'
```

I don't know what symphony is, but if you are trying to assign an array to index `b` here's how:

```
$yaml[UtilInc::getSfEnvironment()]['a']['b'] = array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '15', '16');
```

or if you want to have each element single quotes `'`:

```
$yaml[UtilInc::getSfEnvironment()]['a']['b'] = array("'1'", "'2'", "'3'", "'4'", "'5'", "'6'", "'7'", "'8'", "'9'", "'10'", "'11'", "'12'", "'13'", "'15'", "'16'");
```

Comment: Already tried this. I think framework doesn't matter here. Have you tried outputting more than `a` instead of just one `a`? Try my string.

Comment: It appends square bracket in it=> `a: { b: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '15', '16']}` but still works. Thanks!